# How to loop in bash script?

Tags: bash

i have following lines in a bash script under Linux:

```
...
mkdir max15
mkdir max14
mkdir max13
mkdir max12
mkdir max11
mkdir max10
...
```

how is the syntax for putting them in a loop, so that i don't have to write the numbers (15,14..) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [for-loop](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/)

Answer (score 19):

with bash, no need to use external commands like `seq` to generate numbers.

```
for i in {15..10}
do
 mkdir "max${i}"
done
```

or simply

```
mkdir max{01..15} #from 1 to 15

mkdir max{10..15} #from 10 to 15
```

say if your numbers are generated dynamically, you can use C style for loop

```
start=10
end=15
for((i=$start;i<=$end;i++))
do
  mkdir "max${i}"
done
```

Answer (score 9):

No loop needed for this task:

```
mkdir max{15..10} max0{9..0}
```

... but if you need a loop construct, you can use one of:

```
for i in $(seq [ <start> [ <step> ]] <stop>) ; do
     # you can use $i here
done
```

or

```
for i in {<start>..<stop>} ; do 
     # you can use $i here
done
```

or

```
for (( i=<start> ; i < stop ; i++ )) ; do
     # you can use $i here
done
```

or

```
seq [ <start> [ <step> ]] <stop> | while read $i ; do
     # you can use $i here
done
```

Note that this last one will not keep the value of $i outside of the loop, due to the `|` that starts a sub-shell

Answer (score 5):

```
for a in `seq 10 15`; do mkdir max${a}; done
```

`seq` will generate numbers from `10` to `15`.

**EDIT:** I was used to this structure since many years. However, when I observed the other answers, it is true, that the `{START..STOP}` is much better. Now I have to get used to create directories this much nicer way: `mkdir max{10..15}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {1..15} ; do
    mkdir max$i
done
```

Comment: If you want the values 1..9 to be 0-padded, you use {00..15} in bash4